# NSTableColumn bound to a BOOL value

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, key-value-coding, boolean

i have NSTableView bound to an NSArrayController. in my model i have a BOOL field. i'm trying to bind that value to the column. it displays correctly (1 where value is YES and 0 where value is NO), but it's readonly. =( when i'm trying to edit a value i can't submit it -- when i press enter nothing happens, setter is never invoked. column is editable.

i can successfully bind it with IB -- i just bind it as usual and all works. but i can't do the same programmatically =(

that's how column is created and added:

```
NSTableColumn *column = [[[NSTableColumn alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"ok"] autorelease];
[column setEditable:YES];
[[column headerCell] setStringValue:@"OK"];
[column bind:@"value" toObject:self.arrC withKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects.ok" options:nil];
[table addTableColumn:column];
```

i have a problem only with BOOL values, if i bind the same column to some other field (just changing keyPath) all works fine.

Comment: by the way, the same problem with NSTextCell -- i can't edit it..

Answer (score 1):

> it's readonly =(. when i'm trying to edit a value i can't submit it -- when i press enter nothing happens, setter is never invoked. column is editable.

And then, in your code snippet:

> ```
> [column setEditable:NO];
> ```

Your column is not editable. That's why editing doesn't work. Change `NO` to `YES`.

By the way: Is there a reason you're displaying this value as text and not a checkbox?

Comment: originally it was YES.. don't know how it ended up with NO. anyway -- doesn't help. problem is not there. i can access editor after double click, but can't submit value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the table column, not the cell.

Comment: sorry, i didn't describe it well enough. actually, i'm binding column.  the problem is only with BOOL values -- string and integer values are working correct..

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to include a screenshot of the Bindings inspector with the column selected.

Comment: the problem is, that i can make it work with IB without any problems. but i can't make it work if i create column and add it to the table at the runtime process -- it works with other fields, but doesn't work with BOOL fields.

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to include the code you're using to create, add, and bind the table column.

Answer (score 0):

What is bound to arrC which I am assuming is your array controller?

Is arrC bound to an array?  What's are the objects in the array bound to the controller?  Coredata entities?  NSMutableDictionaries?

Comment: arrC bound to an array. in the array -- entitites of my own class.

Comment: Do your own entities have a "setOk:" method (or is "ok" a readwrite property)?

Answer (score 0):

You need a value transformer, specifically NSNegateBooleanTransformerName. Google for Apple's  "Value Transformer Programming Guide"

Comment: why i don't need it if i use IB to bind the column?